# Basic die question (probability)

Tags: probability

Suppose we roll a fair die twice. Let $X$ be the number of sixes obtained and $Y$ be the number of threes recorded. Then, we have:

$P(X = 0 \cap Y = 0) = \frac{4}{6} \times \frac{4}{6} = \frac{4}{9}$

Could someone explain how they got this step by step please?

Answer (score 1):

No 6s and no 3s means 4 possibilities left for each die.  So you have 16 configurations with no 6s and no 3s.  There are 36 altogether, giving
$16/36 = 4/9$ chance of no 6s and no 3s.

Comment: Hello, is there any chance you could please help with the troubles i'm having in the other answer (in the comments)?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably different rolls of a die are independent, and if you get $X=0$ and $Y=0$, that means that both rolls you got neither a three nor a six. But the probability of this for one roll is $4/6$. But since the rolls are independent, we square this to get $4/9$.

Comment: Why is the probability for one roll $4/6$?

Comment: @newmathsstudent3 There are four equally likely possibilities left out of six: $1,2,4,5$. These give a probability of $4/6$.

Comment: I still don't follow. We roll a dice twice, the number of sixes can be either $0,1,2$ how did you get 4 left out of 6?

Comment: @newmathsstudent3 Sorry, so we're looking for the probability that we got no sixes and no threes over both rolls since if we got one we would definitely have $X$ or $Y$ is nonzero. So for each roll, you have four okay possibilities (1,2,4,5) and two bad ones (3,6), all of which are equally likely, which gives $4/6$. The problem with looking at the number of sixes rolled is that they are not all equally likely. You would be much more surprised to roll two dice and get 2 sixes compare to getting no sixes at all right?

Comment: I understand why it's $4/6$ now thank you. Could you elaborate a little more with it not being equally likely if we look at the number of sixes rolled alone?

Comment: actually thinking about it some more, is it not supposed to be independent? I mean, the probability of getting no sixes $X = 0$ is $5/6$, so the probably of getting no sixes in two rolls is $(5/6)^2$? This isn't equal to $4/6$:S

Comment: @newmathsstudent3 Sorry I disappeared for a bit, my phone died. So the problem isn't really that those events don't have equal likelihoods (although they don't and it does complicate it), the problem is that the number of sixes you have affects the number of threes you can get. For example if you get two sixes of course you can't get any threes. This means that the events $X=0$ and $Y=0$ are not independent.

Comment: Therefore the probability that they both happen at the same time is not the product of their individual probabilities, so looking at the probability that $X=0$ doesn't help you too much with solving the problem you want to solve, which is that probability that both events happen.

Comment: Also didn't see your new comment till now. Yes the probability of no sixes is $(5/6)^2$, but the problem is about the probability of no threes and no sixes. And getting threes and sixes are not independent events.

Answer (score 0):

Since $P(A \cap B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cup B)$,
$P(X=0 \cap Y=0) = P(X=0)+P(Y=0)-P(X=0 \cup Y=0) = \frac{25}{36}+\frac{25}{36}-\frac{34}{36}$.

This also happens to equal $\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^2$, but it is easier to understand in the context of this problem. $\frac{4}{6}\times\frac{4}{6}$ is not helpful because it implies several things that are incorrect; note that $P(X=0) \ne \frac{4}{6}$, $P(Y=0) \ne \frac{4}{6}$ and $P(X=0 \cap Y=0) \ne P(X=0)P(Y=0)$ ie they are not independent events. $\frac{4}{6}\times\frac{4}{6}$ is an incorrect answer to this question even though it gives the same numeric result. To demonstrate that they are equal would require simple set theory, which is likely outside the scope of this problem.